# SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy en desarrollo de un CRUD utilizando la extensión PDO solo me falta depurar el siguiente error que me aparece en la parte de MODIFICAR, hice varias pruebas y descubrí que al momento en el que le presento al usuario el formulario de modificado el input del ID debe ir oculto porque lo utilizamos de referencia más que nada ¿cierto? bueno, si yo no lo lleno manualmente (que no es el deber ser) y lo dejo oculto me salta el error mencionado el cual es este:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "" in /var/www/html/Modulos/Fermary/modelo/actualizar-triunfador-modelo.php:148 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Modulos/Fermary/modelo/actualizar-triunfador-modelo.php(148): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /var/www/html/Modulos/Fermary/controlador/form-actualizar-triunfador-controlador.php(21): ActualizarTriunfador->ModificarTriunfador() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Modulos/Fermary/modelo/actualizar-triunfador-modelo.php on line 148

Estoy trabajando con el patrón MVC les dejaré acá trozos de código a ver si podemos solucionar esto, de todas maneras seguiré trabajando y si hallo la solución la comparto con ustedes:

Modelo (acá muestro el método set, el método get con el cual imprimo un registro según el id dentro del placeholder del input que mostraré más adelante):

```
        public function setIdT($id){
            $this->id_triun = $id;
        }

        public function getIdT(){
            $PDOStatement = Conexion::query("SELECT id_triun FROM triunfador WHERE id_triun = {$this->id_triun}");
            $PDOStatement -> execute();
            $idTriunfador = $PDOStatement -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $idTriunfador;
        }    

        public  function ModificarTriunfador(){
            $consultaSQL = 'UPDATE triunfador SET nombre_triun = :nombreT,apellido_triun = :apellidoT,cedula_triun = :cedulaT,seccion_triun = :seccionT,trayecto_triun = :trayectoT,condicion_triun = :condicionT WHERE id_triun = :idT';


            $PDOStatement = Conexion::prepare($consultaSQL);

            $PDOStatement -> bindParam(':idT', $this->id_triun, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $PDOStatement -> bindParam(':nombreT',$this->nombre_triun,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $PDOStatement -> bindParam(':apellidoT',$this->apellido_triun,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $PDOStatement -> bindParam(':cedulaT',$this->cedula_triun,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $PDOStatement -> bindParam(':seccionT',$this->seccion_triun,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $PDOStatement -> bindParam(':trayectoT',$this->trayecto_triun,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $PDOStatement -> bindParam(':condicionT',$this->condicion_triun,PDO::PARAM_STR);


            $PDOStatement -> execute();


    }
```

Controlador:

```
 <?php

       require_once '../modelo/actualizar-triunfador-modelo.php';

        $id = $_POST["Id"];
        $nombre_triun = $_POST["Nombre"];
        $apellido_triun = $_POST["Apellido"];
        $cedula_triun = $_POST["Cedula"];
        $seccion_triun = $_POST["Seccion"];
        $trayecto_triun = $_POST["Trayecto"];
        $condicion_triun = $_POST["Condicion"];

        $obj = new ActualizarTriunfador();
        $obj -> setIdT($id);
        $obj -> setNombreT($nombre_triun);
        $obj -> setApellidoT($apellido_triun);
        $obj -> setCedulaT($cedula_triun);
        $obj -> setTrayectoT($trayecto_triun);
        $obj -> setSeccionT($seccion_triun);
        $obj -> setCondicionT($condicion_triun);

        $obj -> ModificarTriunfador();


        header('location:../controlador/gestionar-triunfador-controlador.php');
```

?>

Vista (Aca tengo el input que les mencioné):

```
    <div class="form-group bounceInLeft animated">
    <label for="Id" class="Nombre hidden">ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="Id" placeholder="<?php foreach($Id as $Triunfador){echo intval($Triunfador['id_triun']);} ?>" class="center-block form-control" >
    </div>
```

Comment: Si el valor del input del que hablas es parte de la condición `WHERE` el mismo no puede ser jamás pasado en blanco o con un valor inválido, como está ocurriendo ahora. En un formulario así, todos los datos obligatorios deberían estar marcados como `required` y los datos numéricos tener el `type="number"` para evitar situaciones como estas. Por cierto, tu método `getIdT()` es peligrosamente vulnerable a la Inyección SQL, no sé si has advertido ese **grave agujero de seguridad**.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta brother, veré como hago para ponerle las cosas fáciles al usuario y que no esté ingresando el ID manualmente tal como lo debo hacer yo, también reemplazaré la consulta de mi método `getIdT()` por una consulta preparada, gracias por la observación me has ayudado mucho :D

Comment: Quizá podrías usar un `select` para mostrar los valores, permitiendo al usuario seleccionar uno de ellos. No sé si sería eso lo que te hace falta, todo depende de cómo sea tu aplicación. No es lo mismo por ejemplo que sean muchos datos o pocos, no es lo mismo seleccionar entre `10`  datos que entre `10,000` datos. Otra opción sería buscar en base a un criterio, por ejemplo, el nombre, y mostrar los ids que tengan ese nombre para seleccionar uno de ellos, etc. O sea, todo dependerá siempre de lo que quieras hacer en tu programa. Te doy ideas solamente... Saludos.

Comment: Hola nuevamente compañeros, el error ha sido depurado, realmente era algo sencillo... compartiré mi experiencia por si a alguien le sirve: Yo estaba imprimiendo mi ID en un input dentro del atributo `placeholder` por lo tanto el ID aparecía en el input pero sombreado y al momento de actualizar los registros obviamente me salía el error que tenía que ver con la instrucción SQL, lo que hice fue cambiar el `placeholder` por el atributo `value` dentro de mi input, y luego lo oculté con `hidden` y todo arreglado, gracias por comentar muchachos :D